# Double precision quotient?

Tags: c++, windows, int, double, precision

I ran into the following problem in a quiz I had the other day.

> Consider the code fragment (assumed to be in a program in which all variables are legally defined):
>
> ```
> int num1, num2;
> double answer;
>
> // program gets num1 and num2 from user, and values received
> // are always non-zero ints between -100 and +100 (code not shown)
>
> ...
>
> // compute precise quotient:
> answer = (double) ( num1 / num2 );
> ```
>
> After the assignment statement the variable answer, will hold the most precise quotient possible, accurate to several digits to the right of the decimal point  ...

So the choices are `always`, `never`, and `sometimes`. I choose `never` due to how the bracket works in this case, however my teacher said it's `sometimes`. I am a bit lost, so I hope someone can explain it.

Comment: Let's say `num1 = 25;` and `num2 = 5;`, then answer will be `5.0` ... so it's:  sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `(num1 / num2)` is parenthesized, and both `num1` and `num2` are integers, it will result in integer division, which discards the fractional part. If the expression had been `(double) num1 / num2`, `num1` would have been casted to double first, and the result would always be accurate to multiple decimal points.

An example where the result is accurate: `(double) (4 / 2)` is the same as `(double) (2)`

An example where the result is not accurate: `(double) (3 / 2)` is the same as `(double) (1)`

Comment: Ok I get it now, for some reason I always thought (double) (4 / 2) would get me 2.0 instead of just 2.

Comment: @Michael: It does. But `2.0` is the same as `(double) 2`.